# How does Blender Achieve Minimal File Size in Exported FBX Files?

Tags: .fbx

I've been using the FBX SDK to write an app that generates 3D meshes from raw data. With tens of thousands of data points, these FBX files can becomes quite large, maybe 600 mb.

I have also used Blender to export FBX files. With similar (or greater) polygon counts, the file sizes are drastically smaller.

What is the secret sauce in Blender's use of the FBX SDK that causes the Blender exported FBX files to be so concise?

I would be grateful if someone could point me to the proper place in the Blender source code for FBX export, so that I can compare it to my code.

Thank you!

Comment: Could be the way data is written (ASCII or Binary) (could also be also a compression level dependant of a variable or fbx version when compressing in binary. 

I'm also looking for a way to reliably could what size i'll have in output depending on vert/edge/face/uv/attribute/textures/etc.. I have.